# AMD Vi error: unable to write to iommu perf counter

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation

I'm getting an error when I try to boot from a live USB: `AMD Vi error: unable to write to iommu perf counter` This happens after the grub menu and before the system boots into the graphical manager.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to /etc/default/grub:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"`

Then `sudo update-grub` and the error goes away. Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63112560/2422617). Works for me with a Ryzen 4350G CPU + MainMSI B550M PRO-VDH WIFIB550

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `iommu=pt` to the end of the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= line in /etc/default/grub; run `sudo update-grub` afterwards, then reboot.

Comment: Didn't work but thank you