# Linux Mint 20: freeze while using youtube

Tags: drivers, freeze, amd-graphics, mint

I purchase a new laptop and then change windows to Linux mint and also change grub

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"

as per suggested:[AMD Vi error: unable to write to iommu perf counter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327463/amd-vi-error-unable-to-write-to-iommu-perf-counter)
because its showing a blank screen, now its working fine but looks like there is still a graphic card issue because every time I am using youtube its randomly freeze or struggle to open video in vlc.

here is the system details:

```
Kernel: 5.4.0-73-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa 
  base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Aspire A715-41G v: V1.02 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: PK model: Azalea_PKS v: V1.02 serial: <filter> UEFI: INSYDE v: 1.02 
  date: 06/19/2020 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx 
  bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen+ rev: 1 L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
  bogomips: 33535 
  Speed: 1233 MHz min/max: 1400/2100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1281 2: 1263 
  3: 1222 4: 1222 5: 1397 6: 1377 7: 1389 8: 1366 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: N/A bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Device-2: AMD Picasso vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: amdgpu 
  v: kernel bus ID: 05:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: amdgpu,ati 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-73-generic LLVM 11.0.0) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6 direct render: Yes
```

not sure it will be helpful or not:  dmesg | grep error

```
[    1.103921] kfd kfd: error getting iommu info. is the iommu enabled?
[    1.104053] kfd kfd: device 1002:15d8 NOT added due to errors
[    7.774746] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    8.090933] snd_rn_pci_acp3x: probe of 0000:05:00.5 failed with error -22
[    8.155206] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.155234] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
```

Comment: Do you get this same error with Ubuntu?

Comment: @rtaft no idea yet, sorry I asked here

Comment: Here you go, they are friendly people and will help you https://forums.linuxmint.com/

Comment: @SagarParikh You would get better support here I think than the mint forums.  If this happens in Ubuntu and you manage to get it fixed there, the fix would likely work in Mint as well.

Comment: Install Ubuntu 20.04 or 21.04 and remember to include third party software with the installation. Then try again. It's possible you didn't include third party software and only the generic driver was installed. This forum only deals with Ubuntu and your question relating to Mint will in all likelihood be closed by the admin. If you install Ubuntu and update your question, your question will be allowed to continue here.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: Ubuntu & *flavors* do not use run-time *adjustments*, because code is modified, new packages are built and there is no need (along with the added risk vectors opened security wise by use of *adjustments*). Mint relies on *adjustments* as it allows them to use foreign (Ubuntu) packages and not create everything themselves (it also means many things on Ubuntu that work are different in Mint).  Only Ubuntu and flavors (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a quite recent system, you could try using later kernel version (5.8 or 5.11). You can do that in the Mint "Update Manager" > "View" > "Linux Kernels".

Another option would be to try whether this also happens with a different Linux distribution as suggested in the comments. Mint has an ["edge" Version](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=287) which has the 5.8 kernel by default.